# In PHP, is there a simple way to get the directory part of a URI?

Tags: php, directory, uri

In PHP, is there a neat way to get just the directory part of an HTTP URI? I.e. given a URI with an optional filename and query, I want just the directory without the filename or query;

```
  Given            Returns
  /                /
  /a.txt           /
  /?x=2            /
  /a.txt?x=2       /
  /foo/            /foo/
  /foo/b.txt       /foo/
  /foo/b.txt?y=3   /foo/
  /foo/bar/        /foo/bar/
  /foo/bar/c.txt   /foo/bar/
```

And so on.

I can't find a PHP function to do it. I'm using the following code snippet but it's long-winded and over-complicated for something that feels like it ought to be a single function;

```
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_dir = substr($uri_path, 0, 1 + strrpos($uri_path, '/'));
```

Is there a cleaner way?

**Edit**

dirname() doesn't do what I want.

```
echo dirname("/foo/bar/");
```

Outputs;

```
/foo
```

Answer (score 7):

[dirname](http://php.net/function.dirname) returns the directory.

Explicitly, `$uri_dir = dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

As well, [pathinfo](http://php.net/function.pathinfo) returns an associative array with `PATHINFO_DIRNAME, PATHINFO_BASENAME, PATHINFO_EXTENSION` and `PATHINFO_FILENAME`. Quite useful.

Comment: just to make it more explicit:  $uri_dir = dirname(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));

Comment: that returns parent dir though

Comment: @Paul Dixon - are you using URLs with trailing slashes or not? (canonical URLs)

Comment: doesn't matter. Try it - dirname('/foo/bar/') returns '/foo'

Comment: how about dirname(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH).'.ext');

Comment: Not quite!..   dirname(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH).'.ext') returns '/foo/bar' without a slash at the end. If you always append one then it fails if $url is '/' because it returns '//'.

Comment: @spot `rtrim(dirname(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH).'.ext'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;` but i don't think it's neat anymore, lol.

Comment: @arvin If $url is '/foo/' then I get '/foo\' back. But changing your function slightly to rtrim(dirname(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH).'.ext'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).'/'; works perfectly. If you think that's right, post it as an answer I'll give you a tick.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner that will pass your tests by stripping everything after the final slash

```
$path=preg_replace('{/[^/]+$}','/', $uri);
```

The dirname function can't help you, as it returns the parent dir of its input, i.e. dirname('/foo/bar/') returns '/foo' *(however, see Arvin's comment that sneakily tacking an extra bit on the uri first would fool it into doing your bidding!)*

To break down that regex...

- the opening and closing braces {} are just delimiters for the pattern, and are ignored.
- the first thing we must match in the string is a /
- then we have a 'character class' in square brackets [^/]

  - the leading ^ means 'invert the class' - in other words, match any character not in this class
  - the next symbol is a /
  - so this character class simply matches any character which isn't a /
- next, a + symbol means 'match 1 or more of the previous pattern' - in other words, match as many non-slash characters as possible
- finally the $ symbol matches the end of a string

So, the regex finds the final slash in a string and all the characters following it.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid regex. I don't like using code I don't understand! (The other thing you mention... tacking '.ext' on the end of the uri first doesn't quite work. '/foo/' returns '/foo'. If you add a '/' at the end, it fails if the input is '/' because it returns '\/' on my windows system. I guess it would return '//' on unix.)

Comment: I'll edit the answer to describe the regex. No need to be afraid of them!

Answer (score -1):

Try `dirname($uri_path);` - see [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

The other option is to use the strrpos() function to find the last occurring `/` which is probably better than dirname as dirname on windows systems treats `\` as `/`.

Then you should check if parse_url() does urldecoding or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
$dir = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // $dir = '/foo/'; // also works
$dir = (substr($dir,-1)=='/') ? $dir : dirname($dir) . '/';
```

also seems to work and is bit shorter.

use:  `'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $dir` for full URI

The reason I would use PHP_SELF instead of REQUEST_URI is that in some of the other examples if the user puts a "/" in one of the arguments, you will get unexpected results without additional sanitizing. Also, not all servers support all header variables, but the ones here are pretty common.

Comment: why was this down-voted, btw? ("_Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases._")